# I am getting the error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()" in the console

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css, vercel

I have deployed my project on vercel but got error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()" despite my script.js file being present in the repository. Can anyone help with it?

I want to get rid of that error and make my project functioning.

Comment: The path must be incorrect. Hard to know since you didn't include any information

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons to why this error my occur. To solve this problem I would suggest :

- First of all make sure all the assets have been downloaded properly.
- Next make sure our files are not under the jsp folder.. Like this :
  `<script src="../../Jquery/prettify.js"></script>`

-Check if the image is in the same path as your script / HTML file.

-Check the name and extension of the image / file. Has a typing error crept in?

For additional info I would recommend checking out [this YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mbge1_elOMA) and google your question by puttting in the title of your question as the prompt. You'll find additional information I have probably omitted.